# AngularJS 1.X apply filter on converted data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

If I use `ng-repeat` together with a `filter` it makes a pretty good search function. But if I convert the data I can't really use a filter to do the searching.

Exmple

JS

```
$scope.ints = [0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9, ..., 99, 100]
$scope.query = ''
```

HTML

```
<p ng-repeat="num in ints | filter: query">
{{num}} in hex {{num.toString(16).upperCase()}}
</p>
```

I would like to search (filter) on both normal AND hex numbers by the query.

This is just an example with numbers but it could also be dates or date differences (like converting a date difference in unix seconds to "4 days ago")

Comment: You could write a custom filter that first converts the number then compares it to the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's note that [a filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) has the following structure:

`{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}`

**The comparator** is used in determining if the expected value (from the filter expression) and actual value (from the object in the array) should be considered a match. It can be used as a function with the following signature: `function(actual, expected)` which should return true if both values should be considered equal.

This allows you to configure it as you see fit and it's very easy down the road to add new equality expressions to it.

#### Here's an example with a strict euality:

```js
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.ints = (function() {
        var toReturn = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
          toReturn.push(i);
        }

        return toReturn;
      })();

      $scope.comparator = function(actual, expected) {
        // This way the filter will display all values if "query" is empty
        if (expected === null || expected === '') {
          return true;
        }

        return actual.toString().toUpperCase() === expected.toString().toUpperCase() || actual.toString(16).toUpperCase() === expected.toString(16).toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query">
  <p ng-repeat="num in ints | filter: query : comparator">
    {{ num }} in hex {{ num.toString(16).toUpperCase(); }}
  </p>
</div>
```

#### Here's an example with a loose equality:

```js
angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.ints = (function() {
        var toReturn = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
          toReturn.push(i);
        }

        return toReturn;
      })();

      $scope.comparator = function(actual, expected) {
        // This way the filter will display all values if "query" is empty
        if (expected === null || expected === '') {
          return true;
        }

        var actualBase10String = actual.toString().toUpperCase();
        var actualBase16String = actual.toString(16).toUpperCase();

        var expectedBase10String = expected.toString().toUpperCase();
        var expectedBase16String = expected.toString(16).toUpperCase();

        return actualBase10String.indexOf(expectedBase10String) !== -1 || actualBase16String.indexOf(expectedBase16String) !== -1;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query">
  <p ng-repeat="num in ints | filter: query : comparator">
    {{ num }} in hex {{ num.toString(16).toUpperCase(); }}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a really good way of doing it. The only problem I see is that it does a "hard" search and not using/allowing wild character search. Say I type `B` it filters it down to `11`, but I would have expected it to show both `B`, `#B`, `B#` results

Comment: Typing `4B` filters it down to `4 in hex 4` and `75 in hex 4B`. I don't know why `4 in hex 4` appears..?

Comment: The reason why `4B` filtered down to `4` was because `parseInt` converted it to `4`. I've fixed it. I'll soon add a way to perform a *fuzzy search*.

Comment: I don't think the correct term is *fuzzy search* or *loose equality*. Nevertheless, I think the second example is what you're looking for.

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If in the ng-repeat you need to show both old and new value, I would create a function in controller to do the transformation, and do the repeat on an array of objects that keep both old and new values:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var original = [0,1,2,3,4]
  var strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  
  $scope.ints = transform(original)
  $scope.query = ''

  function transform(values) {
    var newValues = [];
    for (var i =0; i < values.length; i++) {
      newValues.push({original: values[i], transformed: strings[values[i]]})
    }
    return newValues;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <input type="search" ng-model="query" />
<p ng-repeat="num in ints | filter: query">
{{num.original}} in string {{num.transformed}}
</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you do not need the old value in the ng-repeat the solution is simpler, just call the transformation function on the model.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) { 
  var strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
  $scope.ints = [0,1,2,3,4]
  $scope.query = ''

  $scope.transform = function(values) {
return values.map(v => strings[v])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="search" ng-model="query" />
<p ng-repeat="num in transform(ints) | filter: query">
    {{num}}
</p>
</div>
```

Of course inside `transform()` function you can do every kind of transformations you want

Comment: how many times are the `transform(ints)` going to get called? Say I was getting a relative date string like `"one sec ago"` and a minute pass. Would it be updated to `"one minute ago"`?